# How to solve a differential equation graphically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, graphing-functions

I want to solve the differential equation

$y'(t)=ty(t)+1$, $y(0)=1$

graphically in the interval $[0,1]$.

edit: Graphically means here, how to draw it with pen and paper.

But how do I do this, without any concrete information about $y(t)$.
Am I supposed to get a vector field, or a 'standard function' (like the plot of $e^x$).

Can you explain how to solve such an equation graphically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably what is meant is using direction fields, something like [this](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/dfield/dfield.html).

Comment: On [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), use command like `StreamPlot[{1,x*y+1},{x,0,2},{y,1,3}]` to create a stream plot and trace the trajectory passing through the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but what I meant was how to draw such a direction field with pen and paper and how I get these vectors.

Comment: Compute the steps of the explicit Euler method and draw the resulting piecewise linear approximation. You can not "solve" (in an exact sense) a general ODE in this way, only produce a more or less accurate approximation.

Comment: @LutzL Do you mind writing a full answer, which I can accept? Also could you give an example of the Euler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, drawing a direction field is probably the way to go. For the direction field of
\begin{equation}
y'(t)=ty(t)
\end{equation}
(without taking the boundary condition into account), we can use a computer (if you want the R code, feel free to ask) to obtain
[image]

I assume you are able to find the general solution to this problem. Are you able to see how to use the boundary condition together with the direction field from above to come up with a specific solution to this problem?

Comment: Thank you for the plot, but the question is more on how to draw such a direction field with pen and paper. How do I obtain the vectors?

Comment: @Cornman Every vector on the graph is based at a specific $(t,y)$ pair, at which the differential equation determines $y'$. The vectors are drawn with slope $y'$ and a fixed horizontal component (perhaps thought of as a fixed, small time interval $\Delta t$, while the vertical component is the change in $y$, i.e. $\Delta y \approx y' \Delta t$).

Comment: @jawwheele Thank you. Do you mind giving one example calculation for a specific point? Maybe $(\frac12, \frac12)$.

Comment: @Cornman According to the differential equation R400 used to generate the above plot, $y'$ at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ would simply be $\frac{1}{4}$, so the slope of the vector drawn at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ should be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @jawwheele But how do I calculate this value? If I take a pair $(t, y(t))$, I do not know what $t$ is supposed to be. Or do I just guess $y(t)$ and thats why we are filling the square with all those arrows?

Comment: Without reinventing the wheel, take a look at the following explanation: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DirectionFields.aspx It offers a nice approach with an easy classical mechanical problem, which makes it more intuitive.